# Can we calculate UV Scale Index for UV Light's Wavelength?

Tags: visible-light, wavelength

I am not sure If I am missing something but I would like to know the UV Index is calculated. I am talking about the UV Index that its stated usually on the weather's forecast.

Comment: have you done any searching online that you can share?

Answer (score 0):

> The U.S. National Weather Service calculates the UV Index using a computer model that relates the ground-level strength of solar ultraviolet (UV) radiation to forecasted stratospheric ozone concentration, forecasted cloud amounts, and elevation of the ground.
>
> The calculation done by some other nations also includes ground observations. The calculation starts with measurements of current total ozone amounts over the entire globe, obtained via two satellites operated by the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration. These data are used to produce a forecast of stratospheric ozone levels for the next day at many points across the country. A computer model uses the ozone forecast and the incident angle of sunlight at each point to calculate the strength of UV radiation at ground level. Sunlight angle is determined by latitude, day of year, and time of day (solar noon). The strength of UV radiation is calculated for several wavelengths between 280 and 400 nm, the full spectrum of UVB (280-314 nm) and UVA (315-400 nm) radiation.

Please see the article where the citation is from:

https://www.epa.gov/sunsafety/calculating-uv-index-0